# LaTeX Warning: Citation 'wallerman' on page 9 undefined on input line 255

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I'm having trouble citing something from my bibliography. I keep getting this error: `LaTeX Warning: Citation 'wallerman' on page 9 undefined on input line 255.` What does it mean, and I how do I fix it? Unlike other users, I'm using the "thebibliography" environment of bibtex instead of a separate file.

Line 255: `Here's something from Mr. Wallerman \cite{wallerman}:`
My Bibliography:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{wallerman} 
Wallerman \texttt{wallerman}. 
\textit{doc}. 
March 2014. 

\bibitem{einstein} 
Albert Einstein. 
\textit{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. (German) 
[\textit{On the electrodynamics of moving bodies}]. 
Annalen der Physik, 322(10):891–921, 1905.

\bibitem{knuthwebsite} 
Knuth: Computers and Typesetting,
\\\texttt{http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/\~{}uno/abcde.html}
\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: you have `\cite{aimelist}` in your document, and no such entry in the bibliography.

Comment: oops that's not the error I posted the wrong thing :) fixed

Comment: Welcome! You can't use BibTeX with `thebibliography` environment. If you use the latter, you don't use BibTeX. If you use BibTeX, you need a `.bib` file. Please provide a complete example so we can see what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @cfr pointed out "bibtex"/"biblatex" cannot be used in conjunction with the "thebibliography" environment.

For some reason, biblatex was loaded as a package which is probably what caused the error.

Thanks!